# PHP HTML DOM Parser : trying to parse a file by excluding elements and export in CSV

Tags: php, dom, csv, wget

That is my problem : I'd like to collect the content of around 1000 URL in a textfile (I use the wget function in a bash). And then I want to parse this textfile in order to pick one type of content up in a csv file.

1) So my bash is this one :

```
file=/home/julien/tests/file.txt
for i in $(cat $file)
do
wget $i -O ->> songs_t.txt;
done
```

It works perfectly and the textfile songs_t.txt is well created.
That textfile contains the content of the 1000 URLs.

2) Then I make a php script to parse songs_t.txt. I only want to get concert setlists (the setlist is only a part of a the content of each URL). So my approach is to remove tags such as 'a', 'h4', 'Title' and so on and save the rest in a csv file called 'SONGS.csv'
An example of a URL can be seen here : http://members.tripod.com/~fun_fun_fun/8-17-63.html

My part of the php script dealing with the parsing is this one :

```
$html = file_get_html('songs_t.txt');
foreach ($html->find('title, script, div, center, style, img, noscript, h4, a') as $es)
$es->outertext = 'title, script, div, center, style, img, noscript, h4, a';

$f = fopen('SONGS.csv', "w");
fwrite ($f, $html);
fclose($f);
```

The script works for the 35 first URL (I nearly only get the setlists) but as soon as the script has to deal with more than 35 URL, I have the following error message :

```
 Call to a member function find() on a non-object in /home/julien/tests/boys2.php on line 23.
```

That line 23 corresponds to :

```
foreach ($html->find('title, script, div, center, style, img, noscript, h4, a') as $es)
```

As if there was a kind of limitation...
Could you help me please ? Thanks !

Comment: You're not testing if "getting HTML" from file does not return null. You're also not checking if found element is a valid object. Check your data and print what it contains on error to debug.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. But how can I do to test if my element is a valid object ? And why would it work for only 35 URL (it would mean that the found elements are valid objects), and not more ?

Comment: Use `is_object()` or something similar. Also assign `->find()` results to a variable before loop and then iterate over collection you'll get. That way you won't use `$html` variable anymore and won't get bitten by its state.

Comment: Ok, so I tried `$html = file_get_html('songs_t.txt');
if (!is_object($html)){
echo "invalid object";
}` and the result is "invalid object". This test is made in a textfile composed of the content of 50 URL. But when I apply that test on textfile composed of 30 URL, I have no error. So how can I do to parse my HTML even if it's not a entire valid object ?

Comment: What's more, I follow your other instructions with that code `$dom = $html->find('title, script, div, center, style, img, noscript, h4, a');
foreach ($dom as $es){
$es->outertext = 'title, script, div, center, style, img, noscript, h4, a';
}

$f = fopen('SONGS.csv', "w");
fwrite ($f, $dom);
fclose($f);`. But I have the following error message : `Call to a member function find() on a non-object in /home/julien/tests/boys2_2.php`. Could you help me by posting your code ?

Comment: I'm still on that problem but I really get stuck. Would someone have an idea ?